# Docker - Execute a bash when running a container

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this part of my `docker-compose` file:

```
php-fpm:
    build: ./docker/php
    container_name: php-fpm-symfony
    links:
        - db
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
        - 8448:8448
        - 8000:8000
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
    volumes_from:
        - data
    tty: true
    env_file:
        - ./docker.env
    entrypoint: /command.sh
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0.8-fpm
ADD command.sh /command.sh
RUN chmod 777 /command.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/command.sh"]
```

My `command.sh` at the root

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git config --global user.email "${gitEmail}"
git config --global user.name "${gitName}"
```

I need to execute my `command.sh`file when I'm doing my `docker-compose up -d`

But it does not work that way.

> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot link to a non running container:
>   /php-fpm-symfony AS /nginx/php-fpm ERROR: Encountered errors while
>   bringing up the project. Error response from daemon: Container
>   7c2a9bffa9664c4007d685f56d17e4659c6dd7021962d6462177480f5a821d44 is
>   not running

How can I make this work?

Comment: Could you share the content of `command.sh` it seems that the script is indeed invoked but it is finished immediately

Comment: @cml.co I just did it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A docker container exits when its main process finishes.

Your script is certainly finishing and no php process is launched. Try adding a call to `php-fpm`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git config --global user.email "${gitEmail}"
git config --global user.name "${gitName}"
php-fpm
```